# Share Image in iOS app from Share Extension with groups. With out using Image Data

Tags: ios, swift, image, openurl, share-extension

I want to send multiple images. Share extension to iOS app. With out using Image data. Because while using image data app is crashing when I add more then 10-15 images

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.image") 
{

     itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.image", options: nil, completionHandler: 
      { (item, error) in

                        var imgData: Data!
                        if let url = item as? URL {
                            imgData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
                            self.arrImageData.append(imgData)
                        }

                        if self.counter < 1
                        {
                            self.naviagteToOpenApp()
                        }
      })
 }
```

Comment: you can do base64 encoding to that data and send to your app then decode from there, check this approach it might help you

Comment: @karthikeyan thanks for reply.
But app is crashing while creating image Data.
and getting following error.

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=120 MB, unused=0x0).

Comment: dispatch your data conversion into background thread and check above suggestion if any issue occures

Comment: If i use to send Image URL paths of photo library in iOS app. then FileManager not exists contect of file at path.
but same path exists file in Share Extension why?

Comment: not sure but it may be because of two targets

Comment: @SurendraSharma i've same problem, do you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Hello @Axel sorry for late response. We add max 10 images limits.